# What is this SwiftUI view called?

Tags: swift, swiftui

What is this SwiftUI popup View called (The one that says that I have earned 30 Bits)?
[image]

Comment: This sort of UI component is often called a “toast notification”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of a standard UI component that causes a view like that to pop up, there is none.

However, you can create one yourself.

The basic frame is most likely a `Capsule`, which you can create by doing this:

```
VStack {
  Text("My info")
}
  .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
  .background(
    Capsule()
      .fill(Color.white)
  )
```

You can put that on top of the rest of your view hierarchy using a `ZStack`